# Analyzing Continuity of a Piecewise Function and Addressing Discontinuity at the Excluded Point

Tags: general-topology, continuity, asymptotics, piecewise-continuity, euclidean-domain

This year, in one of the exercises for university admission in the subject of Mathematics in Spain, it states the following:

Given the real function of a real variable defined over its domain as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{2+x^2} & \text{if} & x \leq -1 \\
\frac{2x^2}{3-3x} & \text{if} & x > -1
\end{cases}.$$

And I'm asked to study the continuity of the function in $\mathbb{R}$. My question is, if we realize that the domain of the function is $Dom(f) = \mathbb{R} - \{ 1 \}$, how should I answer the question that it's not continuous at $x=1$? This point doesn't belong to the domain, so it doesn't make sense to study continuity there, right? Some professors calculate the one-sided limits to realize that there's a vertical asymptote at $x=1$. What would be the formal definition of continuity for a function, from a topological perspective?

Any thoughts or suggestions you'd like to share would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: This really boils down to semantics. Personally, I would argue that the question is ill-posed as the function isn't even defined on $\mathbb{R}$. From a more practical point of view, in your position, I would probably just prove that the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$ and mention explicitly that it is not defined hence not continuous at $1$. Besides, the topological definition of continuity is that the preimage of every open set is open, but this is not going to help you much here.

Comment: But if a point doesn't belong to the function's domain, does it make sense to talk about the continuity or lack of continuity of the function at that point? That's my question...
The issue is, if a student states they will only study the continuity in ℝ∖{1} and doesn't mention anything about 1, could they lose points? I don't think so, but how can you argue the claim that it only makes sense to study the continuity of the function at the points that belong to the domain?

Comment: As I said, I personally would not even pose this question the way it is stated and I agree with you that it only makes sense to talk about continuity on the domain of the function. But I have definitely seen other professors ask questions asking whether a function defined on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{p\}$ is continuous at $p$ and what they actually meant was whether the function can be continuously extended.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R \setminus \{1\}$. Thus it does not make sense to ask whether it is continuous at $x = 1$. But it does make sense to ask whether it is continuous at $x = -1$. Certainly the left-sided limit exists and and is $\lim_{x \to -1^-}f(x) = 1/3 = f(-1)$. Similarly the right-sided limit exists and is $\lim_{x \to -1^+}f(x) = 2/6 = 1/3 = f(-1)$. Thus $f$ is continuous at $x=-1$. Continuity in all other point of the domain is obvious.